# show dialog in MVC3 with jquerymobile

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery-mobile, razor, dialog

How can I show a dialog in a MVC3 form with jquerymobile?
Thanks!

I tried this code:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Info", "Info", "ViewWork", new { @data_rel = "dialog", @data_role = "button", @data_transition = "pop" })
```